# Adding a calendar control using HTML Helper tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to know how to add a `Calendar` using `HTML helper` tags. I found a third party library called [Kendo](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-06-07/html_helper_basics_of_kendo_ui_for_asp_net_mvc_beta.aspx) but is there anything that i could use in the components that are provided in the Visual Studio toolbox it self.

Note: I would also need to colour a selected date, enable/disable certain dates in the calendar

Comment: can anyone tell me how to flip pages in mvc using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Asp.net mvc3 then Try this code..

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Globalization;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace AntiYes.Helpers
{
public static class CalendarExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Calendar(this HtmlHelper helper, DateTime dateToShow)
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo cinfo = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        DateTime date = new DateTime(dateToShow.Year, dateToShow.Month, 1);
        int emptyCells = ((int)date.DayOfWeek + 7 - (int)cinfo.FirstDayOfWeek) % 7;
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateToShow.Year, dateToShow.Month);
        sb.Append("<table class='cal'><tr><th colspan='7'>" + cinfo.MonthNames[date.Month - 1] + " " + dateToShow.Year + "</th></tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < ((days + emptyCells) > 35 ? 42 : 35); i++)
        {
            if (i % 7 == 0)
            {
                if (i > 0) sb.Append("</tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr>");
            }

            if (i < emptyCells || i >= emptyCells + days)
            {
                sb.Append("<td class='cal-empty'>&nbsp;</td>");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("<td class='cal-day'>" + date.Day + "</td>");
                date = date.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
        sb.Append("</tr></table>");
        return helper.Raw(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where should i add this function ? Is it to the HomeController.cs ?

Comment: Its an HTML helper..To use this in the view use this code..<%= Html.Calendar(new DateTime(2012, 4, 1)) %>

Comment: Yes, but i am unable to click on the calendar, change months/years etc. How is this done ?

Comment: just call <%=Html.Calender())%>

Comment: I do have to pass some parameters as well ? When i added the code with 0 parameters it doesn't work. When i give <%= Html.Calendar(new DateTime(2012, 4, 1)) %> I am not allowed to click or change dates of the calendar

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, simply Ddrag a Calendar control from the Toolbar onto your form. Then you can access it's properties to effect the calendar accordingly.

Comment: I think he/she is using MVC, so dragging controls from the Toolbox is not really an option here.